# C-Array Sum using Pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sum

I made this program to find the sum of an array using pointer, but it crashes when I run it.  Why is this happening and what did I do wrong?

```
int GetValue(int *p[], int size)
{
     int i, sum = 0;
     for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
     {
         sum += *p[i];
     }
     return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int Array[6] = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
    int Array_Sum;
    Array_Sum = GetValue(&Array[6], 6);
    printf("Array Sum= %d", Array_Sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, no, all of this is very wrong. Find a good book or online tutorial to help you understand arrays.

Comment: The name of the array is "Array", not "Array[6]".

Comment: There are at least three answers below that show a correct algorithm (and one that should be avoided). The only additional changes I would make are (a) use `const int *a` as your parameter; you're not changing the content, so declare that and live by it, and (b) use an unsigned type, ideally `size_t`, for your object counters `size` and `i`. There is no need to use signed `int` for indexing or size limits in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
>     int Array[6] = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
> ```

declares 'Array' as an array of 6 `int`.  Note well that the declared name is 'Array', *not* 'Array[6]'.  The latter expression, outside the context of a declaration, would designate the element at index 6 in that array if the array were long enough, but the array is not long enough, having only 6 elements, at indices 0 - 5.

If, again, the array were long enough, `&Array[6]` would evaluate to the address of the seventh element of `Array` (at index 6), but you presumably want to pass the address of the *first* element (at index 0).  The expression `&Array[0]` would be one way to write that, but most people would instead simply write `Array`, which is completely equivalent.  That is, you should call your function like so:

```
    Array_Sum = GetValue(Array, 6);
```

You furthermore have a problem with your `GetValue()` function:

> ```
> int GetValue(int *p[], int size) {
>     [...]
> ```

Parameter `p` is declared as a pointer to pointer to `int`.  That is, the function signature is exactly equivalent to

```
int GetValue(int **p, int size) {
```

But what you're actually passing (and indeed what you want to pass) is an `int *`.  You can write that either like this ...

```
int GetValue(int *p, int size) {
```

... or if you prefer, like this ...

```
int GetValue(int p[], int size) {
```

.  Having done so, inside the function you should access the array elements as `p[i]`, not `*p[i]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, John Bollinger! You really helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Correction needed is here:
`p[i]` means `*(p+i)`
so,
`*p[i]` means `**(p+i)`

**corrected function:**

```
int GetValue(int *p, int size)  //*p[] is for passing a 2D array ,pass 1D only as your need
{
    int i, sum = 0;
     for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
     {
         sum += p[i];  //correction here that's why it crashes
     }
 return sum;
}
```

as p already is a pointer no need to derefence it.
live demo here  http://ideone.com/kI1hXA
Thanks @JohnBollinger for pointing its 2D argument in getValuefunction in question.

Comment: I did just as told and I am getting the sum wrong... I changed *p[i] to p[i] and I am getting the sum as 118613685. Could u please tell me what's still wrong?

Comment: lemme check again

Comment: check live demo here : - http://ideone.com/kI1hXA  its working. Upvote and accept if it helps

Comment: @VenuKantSahu, your demo at ideone uses a different type for function parameter `p` than you present in your answer.

Comment: At the live demo, this is the output... Array Sum= 1739389629, After that I changed *p[] to *p and now the Program is working! Thank you sooooo much for all your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MohammedShoaib accept and upvote my answer as it would really help me

Comment: I did upvote it but I have a low reputation since I just created my account! So it says that it got upvoted although it won't display since I have a low reputation

Comment: accepting means that right tick the answer if its the right answer for your question and you are the only one who can accept the answer for your question and it will become green if you accept this and i'm not talking about upvote @MohammedShoaib.

Comment: you will get that tick option just below down vote in every answer to accept it as your answer I hope it will help, @MohammedShoaib

Comment: No @VenuKantSahu, it is *not* a 2D array, nor a pointer to one.  It is a pointer to a pointer.  The target might be the first element of a 1D array of `int *`, but none of it has anything to do with a 2D array of anything.

Comment: I mean passing a 2D array with pointer to pointer i know this fact.

Comment: thats why i have written 2D array Pass

Comment: @MohammedShoaib you can accept only one answer and you accepted someone else answer

Answer (score 0):

I changed some things in your code

```
int GetValue(int *p, int size)
{
     int i, sum = 0;
     for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
     {
         sum += p[i];
     }
     return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int Array[6] = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
    int Array_Sum;
    Array_Sum = GetValue(&Array[0], 6);
    printf("Array Sum= %d", Array_Sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could u please tell me why is it *p and *p[]? Shouldn't it be a pointer array? Also, why is it sum += p[i] and not sum += *p[i]? And why &Array[0] and not &Array[6]? I just started learning programming so I am really confused...

Answer (score 0):

The code is to be changed to -

```
int GetValue(int p[], int size)
 {
       int i, sum = 0;
       for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
       {
         sum += p[i];
       }
     return sum;
 }

int main()
{
     int Array[6] = { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
     int Array_Sum;
     Array_Sum = GetValue(Array, 6);
     printf("Array Sum= %d", Array_Sum);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could u please tell why is it p[] and not *p[], isn't that just an array then and not a pointer? Basically using an array to find the sum of an array, but I want to use pointers... Also, why are we passing with Array and not Array[6]? I just started learning so I am really confused right now...

Comment: *p[] means a double dimensional array like **p or p[][]. In your question we want to find the sum of array elements and not a matrix or two dimensional array. So we are  using *p or p[] and not *p[].

Comment: Thank you so much, Gaurang Vyas! You really helped me out a lot!

Comment: Well you can accept my answer if it helped you in any way.